# What is mdLiveAnnouncer in angular material and how its works?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

can anyone please explain me about `$mdLiveAnnouncer` with this code.

```
module.controller('AppCtrl', function($mdLiveAnnouncer) {
  // Basic announcement (Polite Mode)
  $mdLiveAnnouncer.announce('Hey Google');

  // Custom announcement (Assertive Mode)
  $mdLiveAnnouncer.announce('Hey Google', 'assertive');
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific. Do you just want to know what `$mdLiveAnnouncer` is?

Comment: above code i try to execute but it does nothing. i need some clear answer what is this?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Do you have a screen reader enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.3/api/service/$mdLiveAnnouncer).

> The $mdLiveAnnouncer service is internally used for components to provide proper accessibility.
>   $mdLiveAnnouncer.announce(message, politeness);
>
> Announces messages to supported screenreaders.

When you say it does nothing...have you tried running it on a device with a supported screenreader?

According to the documentation on GitHub(linked in the above documentation):

> - Both JAWS and NVDA over IE11 will not announce anything without a non-zero timeout.
> - With Chrome and IE11 with NVDA or JAWS, a repeated (identical) message won't be read a second time without clearing and then using a non-zero delay. 
>     (using JAWS 17 at time of this writing).

Comment: Superb. can you please share me some example for that.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. You have code above. [Here is documentation](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7031755?hl=en) about the built-in screen reader in Chrome. It shows how to turn it on and off.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: That documentation help's me lot. Thk you